# Navbar disappears on resizing

Tags: html, nav

My Navigation bar disappears when the web page is shrinks, even clicking on the  toggler when the page shrinks doesn't display the links at all. I am using bootstrap 4.0 and linking to cdn links
for both the css and other JavaScript needed and it keeps disappearing.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>


      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-2 top-bar" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item collections">
            <a class="nav-link collections" href="#">Services</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-firstmenu">
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">2014 <span class="dropdown-caret"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">2014 <span class="dropdown-caret"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">2014 <span class="dropdown-caret"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">2014 <span class="dropdown-caret"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></span></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item collections">
            <a class="nav-link collections" href="#">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Support</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Downloads</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <!-- drop down -->
          <li class="nav-item collections">
            <a class="nav-link collections" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <!-- end drop down -->
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">My Account</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you include jquery? Did you check your console for any errors when you click on the menu button at all? The console might give you some insight to what is happening or what you may be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by downloading the bootstrap 4.0 css and changing the navbar display from `display:none` to `display:block`